# OpenCV: How to merge multiple lines into one curve

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on school project in which i have to detect horizon in image. We have to use openCV. I got to the point where i can successfully detect horiton in image by using canny edge detector and Probabilistic Hough Transform. Here is my result:

[Image with detected horizon](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/1374/zzgp.jpg)

As you can see line which is showing location of horizon is composed from multiple lines. 
My teacher is fine with accuracy of horizon detection, but he wants me to merge this multi-line into one curve.

Is there easy way to do it??

I am kinda new in programing so every help would be greatly appreciated.

And I want to apologise for my bad english.

Edit 1. :
This is how i am creating lines:

```
  vector<Vec4i> lines;
  HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 1, 1, 200 );
  for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
  {
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    line( src, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
  }
```

Comment: In what format are your line-segments currently represented?

Comment: I have updated main topic with code which is creating line-segments. So i guess its called Cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: And what kind of format would you like to get in the end? :-)

Comment: I dont care much about format i just need to make single curve which will have same thickness everywhere.  Here is an example what my teacher wants. http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/7457/zu7d.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hough-transform you mention usually returns all lines found in a picture (above a given threshold). They do not need to be continuous and can be in completely different locations and directions.

In your case they surprisingly follow the horizon pretty well. You could proceed by collecting all starting and/or end points, sorting them by x-coordinate and drawing with e.g. [polylines](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines).

However, considering the example image given, I would also try some different approaches altogether. For instance Canny edge detection with a big Gaussian and high threshold, active contours or just the strongest vertical-gradient (Sobel) in each image-column.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, ill try to use polylines. In the meantime my teacher responded to my email with this: I should find path of same colored pixel from smallest x-coordinate to highest x-coordinate. What do you think about that??¨

Comment: What's the meaning of color in a b/w-image? If you want to solve this only for that particular image, treating each column individually (finding the darkest pixel as by your teachers input or the steepest gradient as in my very last point) will probably work but not be stable in a more general case, e.g. with a bird in the sky.

Comment: Is there anything more you would like to know? Otherwise consider [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks!